# My Blender v2.83 didn't show "follow path" after press Ctrl+P

Tags: tracking, parent, path

Why are there no follow path options for the camera after pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>?

Comment: @Nxdhin2005 While constraints can be used to achieve the follow path function as well, the Ctrl+P shortcut under the right conditions gives the **Follow Path** function as well. See answer for details.

Comment: I never knew this could be done

Answer (score 1):

To make a camera follow a path:

1. Add in a path
2. Select the camera
3. Go to object constraint properties and select follow path
   [image][image]
4. Check fixed position , Follow curve and curve radius
   [image]

Blender 2.79 had a hotkey `Shift +Ctrl+C` to add constraints

Answer (score 1):

The **shortcut** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> will only show the **Follow Path** option if the camera and the curve object are both selected and the curve object is the active(last selected) one, like shown below:
[image: follow path]

This way goes around constraints and is only based on the curve and it's parameters, thus changing the way the camera follows and it's behavior can be adjusted using the **Path Animation** of the curve:
[image]

The default behavior is that the follow operation starts at frame 0 and due to that the animation starting at frame 1 skips 1 frame.
This can be adjusted in the graph editor:
[image]

Be aware that the relative location of the camera when following the curve is kept based on the start point of the curve. To get the camera start at the exact position of the start point of the curve you'd have to place the camera there manually. The banking and roll of the camera will follow the curve and it's tilt(can be adjusted in edit mode of the curve by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), allowing for some nice curves (no pun intended).
[image]